Why the renderded edge of Volume looks dark?
I made a cylinder to hold a Gaussian beam. The intensity is calculated by the equation of the Gaussian beam. And the material is set like this (I make every choosable color to #FF0000):

The max value of the Intensity output is I0, and the min value is 0. Inside the Node Group is a calculation of Gaussian beam intensity distribution:

In the viewport, it looks like this(I used a transparent background):

After Rendering, it look like this(I use Cycles, and I make a white background in Compositing):

It looks dark, not that red, especially in the surrounding.
I don't want a strong intensity, the red in the middle of the beam is fine, but I hope the color should be lighter red at the surrounding of the beam, not dark.
Thanks for comments. The question is revised.
Thank you.
Reference:

Realistic Gaussian beam: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JVWi-ji-C1Q
Perfect white background: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aegiN7XeLow


My brother in Christ you put all the nodes that would be relevant to the question inside an unlabeled node group where none of us can see it :D Whatever is going on in there is what is creating that value going into the emission strength. If it doesn't exceed 1 then the rendering engine won't consider it as emitting light, only reduce the amount of shadows on it. Try multiplying it by like 10 and see if that makes it brighter.

Also EEVEE doesn't work well with emissive colors, you can only achieve pseudo-emissive effects by enabling bloom. If you're in EEVEE try switching to Cycles and see if that fixes it.

In B4 @troy_s rants about the PNG format and related alpha shenanigans ><

As Gorgious has pointed out: This question is similar to: How to properly render emissive and transparent materials (fire) for compositing. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem and then we can re-open.
